# builtin_function error while making a list of permutations of 123

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to make a sorted list of permutations of 123 but I can't use python's module. When I run this code I get the message:

`'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sort' (line 22)`

```
n = int(input())

elements = str(input())

elements = elements.split

def factor(elements, i , n):

    if i == n - 1:
        return(elements)
    else:
        for j in range(i, n):
            elements[i], elements[j] = elements[j], elements[i]
            factor(elements, i + 1)
            elements[i], elements[j] = elements[j], elements[i]

list = []

list = factor(elements, 0, n)

list = list.sort

while True :
    if list == [] : break
    else:
        print(list[0])
        list.pop([0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one problem:

```
elements = elements.split
```

I think you meant:

```
elements = elements.split() # you forgot the parentheses!
```

Here's another similar problem:

```
list = list.sort # you forgot the parentheses, and the function call is wrong
```

I think you were looking for this:

```
list = sorted(list)
```

Or this:

```
list.sort() # no assignment here, it's an in-place sort
```

Also, a word of advice: it's a bad idea to call a variable `list`, it clashes with a built-in type and a function name. Some final words: what you want to do is already implemented in a standard module, give this a try:

```
import itertools as it
list(it.permutations([1, 2, 3])) # see? told you `list` was a function!
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: split should be called as well

Comment: Of course, that's why the OP is getting that specific error! `elements` becomes the built in method `split`, `list` gets assigned to that when `factor` returns, and then of course `split` has no attribute `sort`. I had been wondering about exactly what caused that, although the `sort` error was obvious.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez thank you much guy. i edited my code but again got error. now it says: 
'NoneType' object is not iterable (line 24) .

Comment: @user3015255 which one is the line 24?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez list = sorted(list)
oh so sory! i saw this site for first time 30 minutes ago ! :) and i didnt know that !

Comment: @user3015255 the `factor()` procedure must return something in the `else` part. And I'm not sure that the algorithm is correct, you'll have to test it thoroughly. If further problems arise, please post them as separate questions, the question in this post was already answered